# MySQL error: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy tratando de hacer un simple login en **PHP**, ya pude hacer el singup pero aún no puedo completar el login porque tengo un error en mi query pero no lo entiendo, he investigado y no encuentro una solución.

```
<?php 


    include("db.php");
    if(!empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['contraseña'])) {

        $contraseña = password_hash($_POST['contraseña'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE Correo = $correo";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
            $rol = $row['Rol'];
            $correo = $row['Correo'];
            $contraseñaDB = $row['Contraseña'];

            if (password_verify($contraseña, $contraseñaDB)){

                if ($rol == 1){
                    header("Location: opencrud.php");
                }else {
                    header("Location: closecrud.php");
                }
            }else{
                echo "La contraseña no coincide con ese correo, crack.";
            }

        }else{
            echo "Ese correo está incorrecto mi bro.";
        }
    }

?>
```

Sé que el error se encuentra en el query en la parte que hago la comparación `Correo = $correo` pero no entiendo entonces cómo hacer la comparación. El error que me da es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que entiendo quiere decir que `$query` no está funcionando y de ahí que no entre al '**if**' y me entregue el '**false**'. A mi parecer no es un error muy grande pero la verdad llevo bastante tiempo intentando solucionarlo y no pude. Si hace falta más información estoy pendiente para brindarla. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Comment: Los valores de tipo cadena deben ser usados con comillas simples en las consultas, por tanto tu consulta correcta debería ser: `$query = "SELECT * FROM registros WHERE Correo = '$correo'"`, **NÓTESE** que `$correo` está rodeado de comillas simples. De todos modos no le veo sentido a un login mediante el correo, el usuario debería escribir su constraseña, no su correo. De ser así, cualquiera que sepa el correo podrá ingresar. Te recomiendo también que evites el uso de `ñ` o acentos en todo lo que sea nominal. Si no estableces bien la codificación el código se romperá y tendrás errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias, con las comillas sí ingresó al **if**. Y lo que hago con el correo es primero validarlo y luego, si el correo existe, hago la comparación de la contraseña. A mi parecer está bien, pero yo no sé mucho, entonces puede se deba hacer de otro modo. Y por lo de los carácteres especiales, tiene razón, gracias, lo arreglaré.

Comment: Ohh, ok, entiendo, no había visto esto: `if (password_verify($contraseña, $contraseñaDB)){`

Comment: Aunque no entiendo por qué usas `password_hash` aquí ¿? Eso es para insertar la contraseña hasheada al momento del `INSERT`, cuando se crea el usuario.

Comment: @A.Cedano Creí que podía compararlas así. ¿Sabes cómo puedo compararlas entonces?, porque si me está dando un error en esa comparación que tampoco entiendo. Te agradezco.

Comment: Simplemente así: `if (password_verify($_POST['contraseña'], $contraseñaDB)){`, como y dije, el hash es al momento de crear al usuario **únicamente**.